# How to parse this Json-String with Gson?

Tags: android, json, multidimensional-array, gson

I want to parse a Json string from a web-api. Here is it:

```
{
"RANDOM_ID": {
  "lnk_typ": "pdf",
  "lnk_description": "Description 1",
  "lnk_link": "https://example.com",
  "direktdownload": "https://example.com/download1"
},
"RANDOM_ID": {
  "lnk_typ": "lnk",
  "lnk_description": "Description 2",
  "lnk_link": "https://example.com",
  "direktdownload": "https://example.com/download2"
}
}
```

**Now my problem:**

> RANDOM_ID could be every positive number, so it could be 230 or 5 (or
> every other positive number).
>
> Also the number of objects can change, i
> mean there could more than just 2 RANDOM_ID-Objects.

And i want to know, how to parse this Json. I prefer to do this with Gson, but it could be parsed manual too, if there is a way to do this.

Comment: I would change the structure of data from api if possible. is it possible?

Comment: Already asked multiple times... Custom serializer or dictionary

Comment: Yes it is possible.Tthank you for your answers! I will try to modify the apis output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a class that represent your json string
You can do it manually or generate it with : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ ( set your package name, a class name, choose json as source type and gson as annotation style )

Then you can get item from object like this :

```
MyObject.getLnkTyp();
```

Comment: yes i tried,  but it isnt easy to get the random id with this method.